# New iPad layout but keep iPhone size class layout the same

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I created a layout in the "any any" size class. Then, I decided to change the iPhone one ("compact width").

I would like to create a new layout for the iPad now. Though, when I delete some constraints in the iPad size class, then they get deleted in the iPhone size class as well.

How can I keep the layout of the iPhone size class while changing the one of the iPad size class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uncheck this **installed checkbox** when you in **compact width** i.e iphone design and don't delete you constrains

[image: uncheck **installed** checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete the constraints for the different size classes, just disable them. Deleting them from one size class actually deletes them from everything.